# Getting perpendicular direction from a direction vector

Tags: math, vector, direction

Given a direction vector from the center of one circle to another, I would like to extract different positions from where a point could go from one circle to another, being the start position perpendicular to the direction vector.

Like in this drawn:

[image]

I would like to generate randomly possible paths. Also, can I get the new direction vector of the possible path with just some quick operation using the center to center direction vector?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

One perpendicular vector is:

```
p = (-v.y, v.x)
```

You can use this to sample possible start positions:

```
startPosition = center + normalize(p) * rnd(-radius, radius)
```

where `rnd(a, b)` gives a random number in `[a, b]`.

The new direction is then simply:

```
dir = secondCircleCenter - startPosition
```